# I seek to unease but leave without a scar

Tags: riddle, word, poetry, limerick

> My first brings in the light from the stars
>   The other is preferred before the time of cars
>   Before you even knew
>   I am born within you
>   I seek to unease but leave without a scar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You know what - you really are a:

> **NIGHTMARE**!

*My first brings in the light from the stars*

> **NIGHT** 'brings in the light from the stars'.

*The other is preferred before the time of cars*

> Before cars, most long-distance travel occurred under horse power - a **MARE** is a female horse.

*Before you even knew*
*I am born within you*
*I seek to unease but leave without a scar*

> Nightmares occur during your sleep, when you are unaware. They cause fear, discomfort and 'unease', but when you wake up they leave no physical 'scar'. (Unless you thrash around a lot in your sleep, of course. Like this one time, I smashed a glass on my bedside table, and... well, that's another story!)

Answer (score 3):

My guess is

> **HEART**

*My first brings in the light from the stars*

> “Heart” begins with **H** for hydrogen or **He** for helium, and the nuclear fusion of hydrogen to helium makes stars glow.

*The other is preferred before the time of cars*

> **Art** is something humanity has enjoyed since prehistory.

*Before you even knew*
*I am born within you*

> Your heart is an organ inside your body, and you were born with it, before you had much knowledge of anything.

*I seek to unease*

> The function of the heart is to move blood around the body, that is, to disturb it.

*but leave without a scar*

> May be metaphorical, representing grief over a love interest (**heartbreak**), feeling much less enthusiastic about something (**losing heart**), or feeling apprehensive (**having your heart in your mouth**), each of which can hurt without there being any physical wound. More literally, **heart attacks** and other heart problems are common causes of death, but don’t cause the surface of the skin to tear.